# How to make particles move in torus

Tags: animation, particles, bezier-curves

I want to make something like a torus with particles in its volume and make those particles follow the curve of torus in one direction. Is there any way to make particles follow an elliptical path?

Here I created a torus with randomized hair particles in volume but I would like particles to follow the curve of torus.
[image: Torus with hair particles]

Is it possible to create a cylinder with hair particles, then add a curve modifier and make it follow the same curve (or with emitter instead of hair)? I don't want particles to deform and it would be even better if those particles can kind of vibrate. Any solutions are welcome.

Comment: did u ever try curve guide?

Comment: I just tried with curve and added force to it and it worked after changing a few parameters :)